# how to set width of DropDown window in object choice field? customized

Tags: blackberry

i am using an ObjectChoiceField in blackberry now. I have items in String array like "a", "abc", "abcdefg" etc. The application automatically sets the width based on the width of the choice items. I want the dropdown window in ChoiceField having width static which can hold the largest entry in the string array.

My question is, Can i set the dropdown window size? if yes, How could i set the width of the DropDown window (which displays all choice items of your choice field)?

Comment: What the hell you have done....
Your que and your answer both are wrong...

Comment: @BBExpert: sorry friend, i am new to this environment.. I wanted to design a choicefield which uses exactly half the size of its layout's width.. Even though i got it working for me.. Again plz put the right code.. It will be useful for others like me..
thanks for ur response

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i had created a custom choice field..

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ObjectChoiceField;

/*
 * The MyChoiceField is actually an extended class of ObjectChoiceField.
 * In this, the design of an ObjectChoiceField is overloaded with providing some additional 
 * tasks is done. It includes a constructor and a Layout methods.
 * In that Layout method the design for the ObjectChoiceField is overrided... 
 */
public class MyChoiceField extends ObjectChoiceField 
{

    public MyChoiceField(String label ,Object[] choices) 
    {
        super(label, choices);
    }


    protected void layout(int width, int height) 
    {
        setMinimalWidth(width/2-62);
        super.layout(width, height);
    }

}
```

Now i got it...

thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. In the current implementation, the drop down size is the size of the largest elements.[image]

My guess is you want the size of the "highlighted" element after selection to be of the size of largest element?[image: Larger size of highlighted element]

And here it is smaller

[image: Smaller size of highlighted element]

Clarify what exactly you intend to do?

Comment: thanks for ur help first. actaually i want to set the size of my drop down menu item to the maximum. and now i had achieved by creating my own choice field by extending objectchoice field. [link]http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/custom_fancy_er_choicefield_for     and         http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-objectChoiceField-doesn-t-display-selected-choice-on/td-p/196606           and http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Fixed-a-Width-of-ObjectChoiceField/td-p/538079 are some good references..... it helped me very much.. Thanks

Comment: For this you can create a custom. It is possible to create our own ChoiceField with specified fixed width.